# Should I clear table view before using reloadData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I want to put new values in a table view.

My `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` has the following

```
if (cell == nil) { // do something }
```

When I remove the if statement on top and use `reloadData` the app crashes. Do I need to clear the old values in the table before I use `reloadData`? If so how?
Thanks

**Edit:**

I'm sorry i didnt mean that i put `reloadData` inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. i put it inside another method and removed `if (cell == nil) { // do something }` from inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) to familiarize yourself with the concepts. `reloadData` is a method that eventually calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating infinite loop by calling reloadData inside

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to clear data in a table view. You may want to ensure you properly implement `-prepareForReuse` in your UITableViewCell subclasses though, so that reused cells don't show old data.

It's BTW unclear why you want to remove the `if (cell == nil)` bit. If there is no cell to reuse (dequeue) then you need to create a new one. If you don't you'll return nil, which will cause an exception in UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

You (99% of the time) can't call `reloadData` from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
This is because `reloadData` eventually calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so you get a never ending loop.

You need to explain more what you trying to do (and some extra code would be nice) in order to answer the question further.

Answer (score 0):

reloadData calls all tableView data source , so you cann't call it in cellForRowAtIndexPath it will make an infinite loop.